# Set a variable with current year in Swift

Tags: swift, date

How can I set the variable `year` to the current year in Swift?

```
let year = ...
```

Comment: https://classictutorials.com/2015/07/how-to-get-current-day-month-and-year-in-nsdate-using-swift/

Comment: How can you vote to close this as too broad? It has a one line answer.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Use `Calendar` and `Date`:

```
let year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
```

Comment: Note `.current` may give unexpected results if the device is set the a different calendar (like `.hebrew`). Use `Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)` to avoid this.

Answer (score 11):

Swift 5 update:

```swift
let year = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).dateComponents([.year], from: Date()).year

// iOS 15+
let year = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).dateComponents([.year], from: .now).year
```

Comment: Note `.current` may give unexpected results if the device is set the a different calendar (like `.hebrew`). Use `Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)` to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I'm updating this answer 

Comment: As of iOS 15 you can substitute `.now` for `Date()`

Comment: adding this info too, thanks 

Answer (score 7):

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current

let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
```

Comment: Note `.current` may give unexpected results if the device is set the a different calendar (like `.hebrew`). Use `Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)` to avoid this.